# Recover curropt Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I've modified an aspx page using Sharepoint designer and now I can't re-open page.
Everytime I try, I get error message below. From other searches it would appear that SPD has corrupted file and how won't open it again. I can however open it as a text file but can't see or don't have the knowledge to see what is corrupted.

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this, otherwise it means I only ever have one change to change a page, which frankly is rubbish.

```
Problem Event Name:         APPCRASH  
Application Name:           SPDESIGN.EXE  
Application Version:        12.0.6606.1000  
Application Timestamp:      4e2f96b3  
Fault Module Name:          ntdll.dll  
Fault Module Version:       6.1.7601.17725  
Fault Module Timestamp:     4ec49b8f  
Exception Code:             c015000f  
Exception Offset:           00084621  
OS Version:                 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1  
Locale ID:                  2057
```

Additional information about the problem:

```
LCID:                       1033
Brand:                      Office12Crash
skulcid:                    1033
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do one thing,

1. Browse the SharePoint site to locate Site Actions.
2. Click Site Actions, and then click Site Settings.
3. On the Site Settings page, click Reset to site definition under the Look and Feel option.
4. On the Reset Page to Site Definition Version page, type  URL for the page, 
   and then click Reset.

Let me know if this helps you.